# Dynamically Read Properties file and draw Text boxes in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

I have a properties file with all the fields. dynamically I need to draw the text box with fields as read from the properties file and enter values and post it to controller in spring - java !

Example Properties File

```
name=String
age=int
address=string
```

How can I do this from java code..

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?  Post some code and we can help

Answer (score 1):

For my idea, I will do it as below:

1. Using ajax to get fields from property file on server and return a list of field and type of field in a json format (key, value).
2. Now we have the data of those fields, then we generate them to your form using jquery or javascript.
3. Submit the form to server to get value.

Step 1 and 2 are quite easy, so I do not post the code; for step 3, you can try the method below to parse the params in query string to a map.

```
public static Map getMapFromQueryString(String queryString) {
    Map returnMap = new HashMap();

    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(queryString, "&");
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String key, value;
        String keyAndValue = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        int indexOfEqual = keyAndValue.indexOf("=");

        if (indexOfEqual >= 0) {
            key = keyAndValue.substring(0, indexOfEqual);
            if ((indexOfEqual + 1) < keyAndValue.length()) {
                value = keyAndValue.substring(indexOfEqual + 1);
            } else {
                value = "";
            }
        } else {
            key = keyAndValue;
            value = "";
        }

        if (key.length() > 0) returnMap.put(key, value);
    }

    return returnMap;
}
```

Now you can get all the value of dynamic fields on the form.

Hope this solution is helpful for you.